# Script shell check validate date format YYYYMMDDHHMMSS

Tags: shell

i want to check if Date is valid or not using Script shell.

I tried this:

```
date "+%d/%m/%Y" -d "09/10/2013" > /dev/null  2>&1
is_valid=$?
```

It works fine for me when it comes to dd/MM/YYYY format. I Tried

```
date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S" -d "20191001041253" > /dev/null  2>&1
is_valid=$?
```

for YYYYmmddHHMMSS but it doesn't work.

Could someone please guide me to check if a date is valid or not with the YYYYmmddHHMMSS.

Comment: `but it doesn't work` - how does it don't work? why?

Comment: Yeah, the `date` free-form parser is not completely magical. There are limits on what input it can handle.

Answer (score 1):

The 'date' utility accept date values in many formats (look at info date, 'Date Input formats' section). The bad news is that the format you need ( 'YYYYmmddHHMMSS') is not supported. The good news is that similar format (ISO compact format 'YYYYmmdd< HH:MM:SS') is supported.

```
date -d '20191001 05:06:07'
Tue Oct  1 05:06:07 IDT 2019
```

If you want to LIMIT the input date format to accept ONLY YYYYmmddHHMMSS, you actually have to write a small filter

```
input=20191001050607
# Convert to YYYYmmdd HH:MM:SS
t="${input:0:8} ${input:8:2}:${input:10:2}:${input:12:2}"
is_valid=
# Validate; Check for 14 digits + try to convert to date
[[ "$input" =~ ^[0-9]{14}$ ]] && date -d "$t" > /dev/null 2>&1 && is_valid=YES
echo "$is_valid"
```

Comment: Don't use ALLCAPS variable names. One day you'll accidentally overwrite PATH (or some other crucial shell variable) and then wonder why your script is broken.

Answer (score 1):

GNU date has a very relaxed syntax as to how to read input. The `"+..."` is only for specifying the output of it, you cannot in any way specify how should it read/parse the input.

You need to first convert your input into something GNU date can understand. I found that the format mentioned in the `DATE STRING` section in [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) seems to be most reliable.

```
s=20191001041253
# 2019-10-01 04:12:53
s="${s::4}-${s:4:2}-${s:6:2} ${s:8:2}:${s:10:2}:${s:12:2}"
if date --date="$s" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
   echo "Its ok"
else
    echo "its invalid"
fi
```

Note that [bsd date](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?date) has an `-f` options that allows specifying input format. I wish such option would be available with gnu date.

Comment: I endorse your last paragraph

Comment: There are [dateutils](http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/) about which I learned just recently and it's available on many distros. There is `strptime` utility that does just what it says and works really well.

Comment: Consider adding  checks on the input to prevent variations that should not be accepted like '20191001041253 foobar'

Comment: @dash-o right. I could see ex. a simple `if [ "${#s}" -eq 14 ] && date ...` or similar

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to `ISO` format:-

```
$ date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S" -d "2019-10-01 04:12:53"
20191001041253

$ echo $?
0
```